# What does values["PromoCode"] reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am going through this tutorial and am confused as to what he is refrencing with the first part of this statement, at first i thought it was the values in the promo code table but there is no model to build that table from. The tutorial link is as follows:http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-9

```
string.Equals(values["PromoCode"], PromoCode,
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false
```

Answer (score 0):

`PromoCode` is a constant

`values["PromoCode"]` is one of the posted values from the form : see in the view

You can access the `FormCollection` (`values` is a `FormCollection`, which stores all inputs from the form, and inherits from NameValueCollection) by its keys : the keys are the names of the inputs.

`<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("PromoCode") // it's not a TextBoxFor
 </div>`

this will generate something like

```
<input type="text" name="PromoCode" id="PromoCode" />
```

It's not linked to anything in the model, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

See the method signature:

```
public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(FormCollection values)
```

So it is a collection of all posted values.

Answer (score 0):

See the signature of the method:

```
public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(FormCollection values) // <-- here
{
    // ...
    if (string.Equals(values["PromoCode"], PromoCode,
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

the `values` is of type `FormCollection`, which means the data collection in the HTML `<form>` posted from browser, the MVC model-binding will gather form data into `FormCollection` instance (the `values` here), so you may get form data by code like `values["PromoCode"]`, which is the same as `Request.Form["PromoCode"]` in classic asp/asp.net.